# Crystal Reports formatting values by parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a formula which shows the decimal points

```
IF {?ShowDecimals} = "Y"
 then 
 Round ({?Box1CY},2 )
 Round ({?Box2CY},2 )
```

Box1CY and Box2CY are my text fields;
ShowDecimals = "Y" or "N"
I want to toggle decimal points. Could you help me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control the display formatting of one parameter using the value of another parameter (unless you wish to write your own Crystal Reports viewer application).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Box1CY and Box2CY are parameters rather than "text fields".
Regardless, your expression is missing the 'THEN'.

It would be easier to help if you provide more details.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm trying to do set their values by checking a parameter value. Box1CY and Box2Y are parameters, you are right